# Improper Integral in Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

How to calculate this integral by using Residue Theorem?
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2+4x+5}\,dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Consider the complex function
$$f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{(z+2)^2+1}$$
and its integral along the counter-clockwise contour $\gamma_R$ given by the segment $[-R,R]$ and the upper semi-circle centered at $0$ of radius $R$. Then, by the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), for $R$ sufficiently large,
$$\int_{\gamma_R}f(z)\,dz=2\pi i\,\mbox{Res} (f,z_0)$$
where $z_0$ is the unique pole of $f$ in the upper half-plane.

By letting $R\to +\infty$, it follows that the integral along the semi-circle goes to zero and, with $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$, we obtain
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2+4x+5}\,dx=
\mbox{Im}(2\pi i\,\mbox{Res} (f,z_0))=2\pi\,\mbox{Re}(\mbox{Res} (f,z_0)).$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, I took it from here but, then I have to approximate and find 0 as R goes to zero but I cannot do this. How can I do that?

Comment: $R$ should go to infinity. What is $z_0$? Are you able to compute the residue of $f$ at $z_0$? Reply as a I comment to my hint-answer.

Comment: Sorry, I was going to write infinity. I found z0 is -1+i and the residue of f at this point is (pi)/(e.exp(i)).

Comment: Ok. Now, are you sure that $z_0=-1+i$?

Comment: I found z0 is -2+i and the corresponding residue is (exp(-1-2i))/(2i)

Comment: Perfect. Then what is the value of your integral?

P.S. Btw, if you are new here, take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour